# IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I am trying to write an integration test for a spring boot JPA application using h2 database. Somehow TestEntityManager is not getting created. I tried look for some help on the forum but could not find any relevant information.

Appreciate if anybody can help or provide some direction.

Thanks.

My code is as follows:

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<Config, Long> {

    Config findByKey(ConfigKey configKey);

}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "testEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "testTransactionManager",
    basePackages = "com.abc.xyz.business.repository")
public class TestPersistenceConfig {

private static final String TEST_PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "emTestPersistenceUnit";

@Bean(name = "testEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "nl.rabobank.rom.exception.manager.rom.em.business.domain" });
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName(TEST_PERSISTENCE_UNIT);

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
@Profile("test")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("sa");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "testTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}

private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("em.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("em.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("em.properties.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

}

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestPersistenceConfig.class})
public class ConfigRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigRepository configRepository;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Config config = 
    configRepository.findByKey(ConfigKey.PURGE_DATE_RETENTION_CALENDAR_TYPE);
        assertNotNull(config);
    }
}
```

POM.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To run tests on IDE such as Eclipse, Intellij -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestExceptionHandlerEntityManagerFactory' defined in nl.rabobank.rom.exception.manager.rom.em.business.TestPersistenceConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.filterConstructors(Enhancer.java:666)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:567)
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot then why are you working your way around it? Ditch your `TestPersistenceConfig` and create an `application.properties` in your `src/test/resources` and let Spring Boot do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Initially I tried that approach but it didn't work for some or the other reason, hence was going for this approach. But after your suggestion and few changes like using annotations like @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "....") and @EntityScan(basePackages = "....") in configuration class it works. Thanks @M. Denium for your direction.

Comment: The fact that you need `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` basically tells me you aren't following the general advice of placing the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in a top level package, which basically disables a lot of the automatic features (like Spring Data JPA detection etc.).

Comment: @M. Deinum, I have a multi-module spring-boot application (for ex: business, service etc...) wherein I have one module with class annotated with '@SpringBootApplication'. This module has dependencies of rest of the modules defined in its POM. In this scenario is it still possible to place the '@SpringBootApplication' annotated class as top level?

Comment: Why wouldn't it. Everything is on the same classpath.

Comment: When a project only has integration tests and is not an application in itself, are we still supposed to use the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in it so as to configure the database connection ?

Comment: @horizon7 I have the same issue. Could you post your solution? My project contains 4 datasources = 4 EntityManagers. I would like to test each one using `@DataJpaTest`. Thanks

Comment: @akuma8 I would suggest to use profiles for your case.I used `@DataJpaTest` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` annotations. Please remove datasource configuration if you have any as that might conflict with `@DataJpaTest`.

Comment: @horizon7 Thanks for your suggestion, I finally found another way to achieve this, I overrode the default `TestEntityManager` to use the mine.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a production type database in tests you must add **@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)** to Test classes.

Just add above annotation to ConfigRepositoryTest class to resolve your problem.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestPersistenceConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class ConfigRepositoryTest {
  ...
}
```