# Tests not working for multiple datasource with spring boot liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, liquibase, spring-boot-test

I am creating unittesting for spring boot application having multiple datasources. (Configuration is heavily inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541844/1534925) answer)

> ```
> @Configuration
> public class DatasourceConfig {
>
>     @Primary
>     @Bean
>     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
>     public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
>         return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary.liquibase")
>     public LiquibaseProperties primaryLiquibaseProperties() {
>         return new LiquibaseProperties();
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     public SpringLiquibase primaryLiquibase() {
>         return springLiquibase(primaryDataSource(), primaryLiquibaseProperties());
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
>     public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
>         return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary.liquibase")
>     public LiquibaseProperties secondaryLiquibaseProperties() {
>         return new LiquibaseProperties();
>     }
>
>     @Bean
>     public SpringLiquibase secondaryLiquibase() {
>         return springLiquibase(secondaryDataSource(), secondaryLiquibaseProperties());
>     }
>
>     private static SpringLiquibase springLiquibase(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties properties) {
>         SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
>         liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
>         liquibase.setChangeLog(properties.getChangeLog());
>         liquibase.setContexts(properties.getContexts());
>         liquibase.setDefaultSchema(properties.getDefaultSchema());
>         liquibase.setDropFirst(properties.isDropFirst());
>         liquibase.setShouldRun(properties.isEnabled());
>         liquibase.setLabels(properties.getLabels());
>         liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(properties.getParameters());
>         liquibase.setRollbackFile(properties.getRollbackFile());
>         return liquibase;
>     }
>
>
> ...
>
> }
> ```

and

> ```
> datasource:
>   primary:
>     url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/primary
>     username: username
>     password: password
>     liquibase:
>       change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.primary.changelog-master.xml
>   secondary:
>     url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/secondary
>     username: username
>     password: password
>     liquibase:
>       change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.secondary.changelog-master.xml
> ```

The application is running properly.

The problem is unit testing is failing with this configuration. I have used `h2` as embedded DB. Added h2 as test dependency and added h2 in datasource URL as well in application.yaml for testing.

application.yaml for testing

```
management:
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"
  security.enabled: false
spring:
  zipkin:
    discoveryClientEnabled: false
    sender:
      type: kafka
      #type: web
  liquibase:
    enabled: false
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
    jdbc-url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
    username: sa
    password:
  secondary-datasource:
    url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
    jdbc-url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
    username: sa
    password:
datasource:
 primary-liquibase:
   liquibase:
     url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
     username: sa
     password:
 secondary-liquibase:
   liquibase:
     url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
     username: sa
     password:
liquibase:
  enable: false
```

Unit testing file

```
package com.foo.bar.car;

import com.foo.bar.car.utils.KSUIDGenerator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/58786742/1534925
//@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
//@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
class CarApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        String h = "Hello World!";
        Assertions.assertEquals(h, "Hello World!");
    }

    @Test
    public void testKSUIDGeneration() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(KSUIDGenerator.generateKSUID());
    }
}
```

I have created a [repository](https://github.com/akshayat/multidatasource/) to demonstrate this.

When I do `gradlew clean check` it gives me following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'primaryLiquibase' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDataSourceFactoryBean
```

Not sure what configuration change I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several adjustments to be done to make it work:

1. Exclude Autoconfiguration for DB and Liquibase in your CarApplication.java

   @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                                      LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class })
2. Get rid of `sping` prefix in your configuration (both in app and test properties)
3. Add liquibase changelog location to test properties

Double check with the setup below in case it wont work after all listed above adjustments (I changed things here and there the way I usually code to make it comfortable to me):

`CarApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
                                   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class })
public class CarApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CarApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

`application.yaml`

```
server:
  port: 9999

datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8888/foo
  jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo
  username: username
  password: password
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db-changelog/primary.xml

secondary-datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8888/bar
  jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bar
  username: username
  password: password
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db-changelog/secondary.xml
```

`DatabaseConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary-datasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.liquibase")
    public LiquibaseProperties primaryLiquibaseProperties() {
        return new LiquibaseProperties();
    }

    @Bean("liquibase")
    public SpringLiquibase primaryLiquibase() {
        return springLiquibase(primaryDataSource(), primaryLiquibaseProperties());
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary-datasource.liquibase")
    public LiquibaseProperties secondaryLiquibaseProperties() {
        return new LiquibaseProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase secondaryLiquibase() {
        return springLiquibase(secondaryDataSource(), secondaryLiquibaseProperties());
    }

    private static SpringLiquibase springLiquibase(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties properties) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog(properties.getChangeLog());
        liquibase.setContexts(properties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(properties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(properties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(properties.isEnabled());
        liquibase.setLabels(properties.getLabels());
        liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(properties.getParameters());
        liquibase.setRollbackFile(properties.getRollbackFile());
        return liquibase;
    }
}
```

test `application.yaml`

```
datasource:
  url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
  jdbc-url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
  username: sa
  password:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db-changelog/primary.xml

secondary-datasource:
  url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
  jdbc-url: "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb"
  username: sa
  password:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db-changelog/secondary.xml
```

`CarApplicationTest.java`

```
@SpringBootTest
class CarApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        String h = "Hello World!";
        Assertions.assertEquals(h, "Hello World!");
    }
    @Test
    public void testKSUIDGeneration() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(KSUIDGenerator.generateKSUID());
    }
}
```

[image: Result :-)]